# How to set region or something similar in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I guess google is predicting my location by ip address, and shows the localized results. However, I don't want it!

[image]

I guess there should be settings about region in chrome but I didn't find it.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Your title seems to have a completely different question than the context of your question itself...

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for your reminder. I've updated the post.